# Set onClickListener on EmptyView in RemoteViews

Tags: android, android-listview, android-appwidget, android-remoteview

I make appWidget with listView. For this I need use RemoteViews. And when I init appWidget ListView I set adapter and empty view (when no content):

```
remoteViews.setEmptyView(R.id.listViewWidget, R.id.empty_view);
```

But my emptyView contains button, and I need to set OnClickListener for it. How I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need `setOnClickPendingIntent`.

```
remoteviews.setOnClickPendingIntent(button_id, pendingIntent);
```

[More Info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html)